# capacitor official push Notification plugin with firebase (FCM) received with some delay time

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor

I'm using capacitor official push Notification plugin with firebase cloud messaging (FCM) and all thing is ok but the problem is the **delay** .. in Android and IOS the notification received within **2 to 4 min**. after publishing the notification from FCM Console. thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

finally solved!..  the problem was in the FCM console, and when I'm using FCM Endpoints to send notification to FCM there is no delay ! and by the way the request as follow :

URL : https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Method : POST
Authorization (Bearer Token) : server Key (you can find it in your FCM Console)
Body (Json object data)  as follow :

1. "registration_ids" : ["userToken", ..],
2. "notification" : { "body": "notificationText", "title" : "notificationTitle"},
3. "data" : { "key" : "value"}